# Gridview How to catch unique constraint value error in a control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview and sqldatasource to bind data from datatable to the gridview .

When I'm updating a value from a cell with a new one , and the value already exists in other cell of the gridview , I will get contraint error for unique value in a new page and it looks really bad for user.

How can I catch that error and display in a label another text to warn the user the value already exists?

So , I'm not adding something to gridview from an event and there's nothing I can catch. 
I need to make a general rule or something and I don't know how.

I've tried this but it didn't worked , is not showing up .

```
protected void GridViewUpdateEventHandler(Object sender, GridViewUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Exception!=null)
    {
       lblForError.Text="Value already exists"; //etc
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to wrap the CRUD operations with the try/catch block.

Use recommendations from the following threads:

[Catching SQL unique key exceptions in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628189/catching-sql-unique-key-exceptions-in-net)

[SQL update command with unique constraint asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7328526/sql-update-command-with-unique-constraint-asp-net)

Comment: okay the problem is that I'm not inserting something so I can't catch the exception. I'm just editing the row from the gridview .